# jQuery preventDefault on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery function as such:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        $('.menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

this works excellent, showing and hiding the dropdown .menu which is currently just a unordered list with list buttons.

However I want to add a login form to the dropdown menu on some page, yet clicking on the input fields in such form will cause the menu to close(hide).

How do I change my code to prevent this behavious

Comment: as a fundamental design practice, shouldn't your menu have a handle for the click event? It just doesn't make sense to me that the whole menu is the close menu button. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/vCzpP/

Comment: You're right that doens't make sense :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to refer to the clicked element and check if it's a form field with the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.dropdown-menu').click(function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).is(":input")) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.menu').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.stopPropagation()` [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the input fields, which prevents the click from bubbling up to parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#input_field').click(function(){ return false; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('div.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(":input")) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.menu').toggle();
    });
});
```